# Track Search Items in Custom VF Search Page

Tags: visualforce

I have built this custom search page for use in our customer portal:

[image]

I was wondering if there would be a way to track the search terms that are entered. Would like to get an insight for what our customers are searching for. I have no idea if this is feasible or not and don't even know where to start.

Here is code for the form where search term is entered

```
  <div id="search-box">
   <form name="frmSearch" id="search-form">
      <script type="text/javascript">
       function noenter(e){
            if(window.event){
            key = window.event.keyCode; 
            } else{
            key = e.which; //firefox
            }
            if(key == 13) {
            var ele=document.getElementById("search-button");
            ele.click();
            return false;
            } else{
            return true;
             }
           }
    </script> 
      <input type="text" id="search-text" name="searchText" value="{!portalSearchModel.searchTerm}" onkeypress="return noenter(event);" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
      <input type="button" id="search-button" name="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="insertSearchTerm()" />
  </form>
 </div>


<script type='text/javascript'> <!--executes search by passing search term to URL-->
    function insertSearchTerm(){
        var searchTerm = document.getElementById("search-text").value; 
        var url="https://c.na11.visual.force.com/apex/portalcasesearch?s="+searchTerm; 
        window.location = url; 
        return false;
    }                
</script>
```

Comment: Slick looking form by the way. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

It all really depends on what your `portalcasesearch` page does. I don't see why you couldn't create a custom object that you create every time someone searches. I would use an autoincrement field for the name and then a text field for the search term. You could then just create a custom report that groups a record count by that text field to find which search terms get used the most.

Comment: Probably, could have a number field on the object. See in the database if the search term exists and increment it if present else create a new record if not. This would help to  handle duplicate search term records while creating records for the object.

Comment: @ShaileshDeshpande that is a really good idea too

Comment: @JesseAltman Thanks for the reply. My apex knowledge is fairly novice and have been trying to figure out how I would go about creating a new record for custom object from apex each time search is executed. Could you provide a very basic example to at least get me in the right direction or point me to a resource that could help me along?